# Launching processes from a Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, service

I have written a C# Windows Service (for use on Windows 8.1 (32/64 bit) and Windows 10) that monitors for certain conditions and when these are met, it launches another Windows Forms application with some arguments that control a message displayed to a user. I'm well aware of the issues of a service interacting with a user session, and the service uses a (slightly) modified version of the MSDN code to launch processes from a service in a user's session which is available here: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSCreateProcessAsUserFromSe-b682134e#content

When the service is triggered, it will happily launch Notepad in the user's session if the launchpath variable I specify has a value of C:\Windows\sysnative\notepad.exe

However, if I try to call my other WinForms application with the command line:

```
string launchpath = "\"{0}Kiosk.exe\" \"{1}\" \"{2}\"";
```

Where {0} is replaced by:

```
launchpath = launchpath.Replace("{0}", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

and the other two placeholders ({1} and {2}) are replaced by launch arguments, the machine on which the service runs logs system error code 123, which this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) tells me means "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

I have tried hard-coding the path, moving the WinForms application so the execution path is also in c:\windows\sysnative however nothing seems to work, I always get the same error in the logs and the application doesn't load. If I make a shortcut to the kiosk.exe application so I can pass in some test arguments, it launches fine.

Has anyone else ever encountered this? I'd be grateful for any advice.

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `launchpath` when the exception occurs (please check - don't guess)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory return different results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720587/why-does-system-appdomain-currentdomain-basedirectory-return-different-results)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I had some parameters in the CreateProcessAsUser() method call the wrong way around. My original call was:

```
if (CreateProcessAsUser(hToken, launchpath, null, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false, 0, null, null, ref tStartupInfo, out tProcessInfo)) { ... }
```

which didn't work, however when changed to:

```
if (CreateProcessAsUser(hToken, null, launchpath, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false, 0, null, null, ref tStartupInfo, out tProcessInfo)) { ... }
```

It worked fine. I'm still not sure why it was able to launch notepad normally, though, but that's a mystery for another day...

Comment: Anyone reading this would expect a variable named `launchpath` to be passed as the `lpApplicationName` parameter, not `lpCommandLine`. It's good to use both, actually. Pass the fully qualified path to "Kiosk.exe" as `lpApplicationName` and then use "Kiosk.exe" or "Kiosk" in `lpCommandLine`.